Error when trying to join a google meeting using react-native-webview
I'm developing an app that connects with Google Meeting using React Native WebView.
Using a more current desktop user-agent I can log into my Google account and enter the Meet App. However, when I try to start a meeting I receive the following error: "Unable to start the video call due to an error"

Here is the webview code I'm working on:
            <WebView 
              ref={webRef}
              mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
              
              originWhitelist={['*']}
              source={{ uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmeet.google.com%3Fhs%3D193&ec=wgc-meet-globalnav-signin&ifkv=AaSxoQwNz1AzSEa3m5TOml4XOTrEIs0CMucWOGIfqQMqH7YHSWWHT1xe403nXuCkACDKvCzEDValYg&ltmpl=meet&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&dsh=S1125067837%3A1716157508945281&ddm=0' }} style={{ flex: 1 }} 
              webviewDebuggingEnabled={true}
             
              injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={debugging}
              onMessage={(event)=>console.log(event)}
              userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0"

            />

Is there any way to get around this error? Thank you for your support
